# Parser for Constituency Tree (Linguistics Analysis API)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsofts Linguistics API. I'm trying to extract specific tokens from the returned tree.  I dont see any type of parser for traversing through the tree in any documentation...

One approach I considered was to use the Stanford NLP parser but It seems a little overkill for what I need.

Is there an existing parser that I could use?

here is sample data that is returned. for example what can I use to extract "NNP" (Tom)

```
[{
"analyzerId": "4FA79AF1-F22C-408D-98BB-B7D7AEEF7F04", 
"result": [ ["NNP",",","NNP","."], ["WRB","VBP","PRP","NN","."] ]  },

{
"analyzerId": "22A6B758-420F-4745-8A3C-46835A67C0D2", 
"result":["(TOP (S (NNP Hi) (, ,) (NNP Tom) (. !)))","(TOP (SBARQ (WHADVP (WRB How)) (SQ (VP (VBP are)) (NP (PRP you)) (NN today) (. ?))))"]  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find my parser-to-tree (and roundtripping) source code at:

https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify/blob/master/WoundifyShared/ParseHelpers.cs

ParseHelpers is a file from the Woundify project. One of the functions of the project is to demonstrate the calling and consumption of APIs from all leading AI services providers (Microsoft, Google, HPE, IBM, Wit, Hound, etc.).

I've edited in a usage fragment from command.cs file:

```
foreach (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken s in arrayOfResults)
{
    ConstituencyTreeNode root = ParseHelpers.ConstituencyTreeFromText(s.ToString());
    text = ParseHelpers.TextFromConstituencyTree(root); // roundtrip
    if (text != s.ToString()) // original and roundtrip must compare equal
        throw new FormatException();
    string words = ParseHelpers.WordsFromConstituencyTree(root);
    string[] printLines = ParseHelpers.FormatConstituencyTree(root);
    foreach (string p in printLines)
        Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I'm looking for but I don't think I'm using it correctly.  I'm sending it this:  (TOP (S (NP (NNP John) (NNP Wayne)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (NN cowboy))) (. .))  and I'm getting an outside the bounds error.

Comment: This is the call I'm using: ParseHelpers.ConstituencyTreeFromText(newSent);

Comment: I've added in a code fragment from command.cs. I'll try to follow up with a more minimal example tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was using that as a guideline.  I get nothing back.  I think the issue is what I'm sending it. (The string)

Comment: I've sent it variations of the string above with no luck.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a trailing ')'. Your example should be "(TOP (S (NP (NNP John) (NNP Wayne)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (NN cowboy))) (. .)))"

Comment: FYI, to debug, I invoked woundify providing arguments of `parse "John Wayne is a cowboy`."